# Unable to run exe from C# Process Class

Tags: .net, winforms, process, cmd, exe

I am trying to execute an .exe file from from C#.NET Process class, but I am Unable to do so. I am able to run the .exe from Command prompt successfully.

Below is the Successful command prompt output

[image]

I am Using the below C# Code . I have not done anything outside the below code.

```
            string output = string.Empty;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftotext.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " -?";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            myProcess.Start();

            using (StreamReader streamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput)
                output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            MessageBox.Show("Output = " + output);
```

Below is output of the above code.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the exe file is in that folder? (It could be anywhere in your `PATH` for the command line use to work.)

Comment: I copy Pasted the pdftotext.exe their (i.e C:\Windows\System32\pdftotext.exe)

Comment: I wonder if you are getting output, but it is simply not what you expect. When you debug, on what line is the message box shown; if the one in the included code then the execution is successful. Then you can use something like Process Explorer to see how the process is actually started.

Comment: It is mentioned in the code .It comes exactly where it is mentioned in the code i.e after using clause.

Comment: I know this is not the complete code, you have not stated explicitly where you are seeing the message, therefore I cannot assume (a large proportion of debugging challenges are unstated assumptions).

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Output = " + output). will this do? Kindly check it generates after the using statment

Comment: Sorry, missed point: improve the *text* of your question. In any case you appear to be receiving output from the exe, you need to focus on the information you are passing to .NET, and how that is being passed to the exe (so look at what it sees as command line parameters).

Comment: Solved!! Thanks to all

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftotext.exe";
```

Do not put entire file path, its just asking for file name.

**EDIT**

See I tried the same code at my end and it gave me the output correctly in my console:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();


            string output = string.Empty;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"TRACERT.EXE";

            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            myProcess.Start();

            //Process myProcess =   Process.Start("TRACERT.EXE");

            using (StreamReader streamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput)
            {
                output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }


            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: Shows Me Nothing (i.e MessageBox.Show(output) shows nothing (empty))

Comment: Try flushing your streamReader. i.e., streamReader.Flush();

Comment: streamReader doesnot have a flush method StreamWriter has a flush method

Comment: oh sry...my bad...let me see

Comment: Solved!! Thanks To all

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Successful execution of this code.I do not why the output of my .exe file was contained in the myProcess.StandardError and not in the myProcess.StandardOutput

I just gave it different arguments "myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-layout   D:\Projects\OCR\Invoices\Sample.pdf" and it worked fine

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        string output = string.Empty;
        string error = string.Empty;

        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftotext.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-layout D:\\Projects\\OCR\\Invoices\\Sample.pdf D:\\Projects\\OCR\\Invoices\\Sample.txt";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        myProcess.Start();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput)
            output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = myProcess.StandardError)
            error = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        if (myProcess.ExitCode > 0)
            throw new Exception(ErrorCode(myProcess.ExitCode));
```